Estoy usando Ef Core con Azure Cosmos Db, tengo una entidad Post que tiene Comments pero un Comment a su vez puede tener Comments, como modelo esto?
Tengo bastantes dudas sobre como modelar esta relación. Entiendo que Cosmos Db es no relacional y las relaciones no se "modelan" como en dbs SQL. Estuve leyendo documentación y creo que lo mejor sería tener un Container de Comments el cual tenga el PostId y el ParentCommentId (este puede ser null ya que quizás es solo un comentario del Post). Pero no se como lograr este objetivo en Ef Core, y tengo bastantes dudas sobre las propiedades de navegación, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

PostId está bien, pero en lugar de ParentCommentId, puedes tener una colección recursiva de Replies, es posible que sea conveniente que un comentario cargue junto con sus respuestas.

@CarlosMuñoz claro el comentario tendría una ICollection Replies, pero no se como configurar esto en ef core, ya que cada Replie (de tipo Comment) va a tener Replies también y así al infinito, tipo Twitter. Te agradezco tu ayuda.
